# How to combine 2 rows with same start date and end date and tag in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this rows in pandas with same start date, end date and tag. How am I going to combine this two rows.

[output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyNx3.png)

I want to have an output like this.

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISFY4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'TAG']).first()
```

`first` gets the first non-NA value for each group. [Read the documentation.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html)

Comment: This one solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We first identify the duplicate rows with the same start and end date using duplicated() and store the result in duplicate_mask.
Then, we use groupby() on the duplicate rows to combine them based on the start and end date while using ', '.join as the aggregation function to join the tags with a comma.
Finally, we append the non-duplicate rows from the original DataFrame to the combined DataFrame.